# Encrypt image on server and show in browser

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, private-key

I need some standard algorithm to do the following

a server (python script) generates an image (jpeg)
this image must be encrypted with a **public** key

then encrypted image will be stored on storage like S3

this image data then can be downloaded and decrypted by browser using users **private** key

I know that RSA pub/priv is limited to data size and not really suitable for large data..

so I guess some hybrid approach should be used where image is encrypted with symetric key randomly generated and encrypted with public key

and then browser will decrypt random key with private key and decrypt entire image with that random key

So long story short - I do not task to reinvent some wheels in security area - maybe there is some libraries exist that can do this task ? (public key encrypt with python - private key decrypt in browser)

Comment: There are a lot of examples for your described "hybrid encrption" available, but unfortunately Stackoverflow is not providing sample code but helping with problems on existing code.

Comment: try googling for [rsa aes js](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsa+aes+js&oq=rsa+aes+js). first result is [hybrid crypto js](https://github.com/juhoen/hybrid-crypto-js)